# Score increase infinite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I used the following logic in the `update` method to track the position of my node, once it reached certain point, it will be removed from the scene, and score will increase by 1.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    println(colorDot.position)
    var checkPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.frame.size.height / 3 + 50)
    if colorDot.position.y < checkPoint.y {
        if colorDotColor == centerBoxColor {
            score++
            colorDot.removeFromParent()
        } else {
            println("unable to calculate score")
            colorDot.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
    println(score)
}
```

The issue I'm having is when the colorDot reached the certain point, it will be removed from scene, but the score will just keep increasing. I'm thinking there is a logic flaw in my code. Here is a screenshot from the console.

[image: colorDot position and score from console]

Comment: Try to add this line of code before you removeFromParent

 NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:colorDot

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, the score still keeps going up.

Comment: Have you tried making your node optional by: var colorDot:SKSpriteNode? ?
Then you need to nil it after removing it from parent aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you are removing the `colorDot` from the parent node doesn't remove the instance from your object. This means the check of the position against the `checkPoint` will pass.

```
// This will be true even if colorDot is not part of the node hierarchy
if colorDot.position.y < checkPoint.y
```

You could extend the check to ensure it is still in the hierarchy:

```
if colorDot.parent != nil && colorDot.position.y < checkPoint.y
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `colorDot.removeFromParent()`, the `colorDot` object still has a position, and unless you delete that object or override it, the `if colorDot.position.y < checkPoint.y` will give true.

Try by adding 
if `colorDot.parent === self` (in case colorDot was added to `self`).